# How to modify a 'cloned' row without changing the original row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, razor

I have a row that looks like this

```
 <tr class="tr_clone">
     <td>
         @part.PartIDLink
     </td>
     <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].MFGNumber)
         @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].MFGNumber)
     </td>
     <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
         @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].PartName)
     </td>
     <td style="font-weight:bold">
         @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
         @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Parts[i].QtyInItem)
    </td>
    <td>
         <input type="checkbox" id="all@(part.ID)" class="part-class" data-partId="@(part.ID)" checked>
    </td>
    @foreach (var actionType in partActionTypes)
    {
          <td>
               @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Parts[i].SelectedActionType, actionType)
          </td>
    }
 </tr>
```

And I have a Jquery function that looks like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tr_clone input.part-class').change(function () {
                let Id = $(this).attr('id');
                let partId = $(this).attr('data-partId');
                var $tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
                var $clone = $tr.clone();
                $clone.find('td');
                $tr.after($clone);
            });
        });
```

How can I make it so that when the 'clone' row is created that it doesn't include the checkBox?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Solved by adding this line to my JQuery

`$($clone).find(".part-class").hide();`